# Read Binary File in SAS

Tags: sas, mainframe

Is there any way to read the binary file in SAS and change the value of
  'E2' and '80' and '93' x  to '-' and then put it back to a binary file ?

`Data null; 
    length pchar $1;
    infile "&SCRIPTNAME..TXT" recfm=F; 
     input pval $1. @@; 
     if pval eq 'E2'x then pchar = '2D'x ;
     file out recfm=N; 
     put pval;
     putlog pval;`

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: data _null_;                                      
     length pchar $1;                              
     infile "&SCRIPTNAME..TXT" recfm=F;      
     input pchar $1. @@;                           
     if pval eq 'E2'x then pchar = '2D'x ;        
     file out recfm=N;                             
     put pval;                                    
     putlog pval;

Comment: so what happen is the value E2 is changed to - but the other 80 and 93 remains in its place and gives junk value

Comment: RECFM i madeas 'N' to represent Binary

Comment: In a Mainframe context, RECFM is the Record Format, which in short means fixed- or variable-length records, nothing to do with content.

Comment: ok.can you help me in replacing the value to hypen

Comment: Sorry, since you'd got some results, I thought something must be OK with the RECFM=N, so searched and found RECFM=N for SAS, so if you think it correct it probably/maybe is. Can you post the code into your question (use the edit link under the question) and format it with the `{}` button.

Comment: I think it would be good to know what you are actually trying to do, and where you are trying to do it, and with with what. X'E2' in EBCDIC, on the Mainframe, is the letter S. X'93' is a lower-case L. You have no code to deal with X'80' or X'93', so  don't expect them to change anyway. Can you show some sample data, what you are currently getting, and what you hope to see. Specify OS being used, character-encoding system being used.

Comment: i created a file and transferred into mainfrmae using binary transfer.  so when i view it in mainframe its in binary format..so i want to convert the continuous occurrence of E2,80,93 (hexa notation ) into - .